# Pass querystring to XSL through module

Tags: 7

I'm trying to do some fancy navigational work within a large XML sheet, and am generating links with querystrings in my transformation.

What I would like to do is parse the querystring within my .module file, and then pass it somehow to the XSL processor.

Essentially, right now I have (without any error handling at present):

```
/* generate hook */
function _xml_import_generate()
{
  $p = $_GET['p'];

  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'xml_import');

  $xsl = new DOMDocument();
  $xsl->load("{$path}/xml_import.xsl");

  $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
  $xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load("feed.xml");

  return (string) $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this...but how do I pass `$p` into my XSL transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to parse out the query string, and then use [`XSLTProcessor::setParameter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php):

```
/* generate hook */
function _xml_import_generate()
{
  $p = $_GET['p'];

  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'xml_import');

  $xsl = new DOMDocument();
  $xsl->load("{$path}/xml_import.xsl");

  $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
  $xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

  $xslt->setParameter("", "p", $p);

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load("feed.xml");

  return (string) $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

Your parameter should then appears as a `<xsl:param />` in your XSLT.

Comment: so in my XSLT i should be able to pull it out by <xsl:param name="p" select="$p" />?

Comment: My recollection of parameters is really hazy, but IIRC, you use it as <xsl:value-of select="$p" /> wherever you need it.